# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../test/testFiles/shadab.jpeg' test cases for file upload using chai

Tags: node.js, testing, file-upload, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test my node API with Mocha/Chai. I created a "test" folder which contain File.js with this code inside and the same test folder contains a folder called testFile in which I have one image "shadad.jpeg". The test.js file contains the following code

```
describe("/POST upload", () => {
    it("it should POST a single file upload", done => {
        chai
            .request(server)
            .post("/upload")
            .field("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .attach(
                "file",
                fs.readFileSync("./testFiles/shadab.jpeg"),
                "shadab.jpeg"
            )
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.body.should.be.a("object");
                res.body.should.have.property("success").eql(true);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

But when I am doing the command npm test, I got the error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../test/testFiles/shadab.jpeg'
```

With PostMan I am testing my api and sending from form-data key as "file" and value as the file "shadab.jpeg". And getting this response.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": "Added Successfully"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: Try to use a full path for your file, it'll be interressting

Comment: Instead of ./filename use path.join(__.dirname,'filename')

Comment: @PimentoWeb Thanks it worked with full path. I tested it.

Comment: @RahulPatil I guess your solution will also work because ```path.join(__.dirname,'filename')```  will return full path. But haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this issue https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/259.
[This comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu7Jf.png) resolved my issue.Check the given github link for more details.
And by using the full path of the file like this `` fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/testFiles/shadab.jpeg`) `` it is also working as mentioned by  Pimento Web in comments.
The relative file path is behaving weird in test folder.
I have used `fs.readFileSync("test/testFiles/shadab.jpeg")` and it is working for me now.As I already mentioned in this question above `test` folder is containing `testFiles` folder and `shadab.jpeg` is in the `testFiles` folder.